# Only home page works after deploy on GithubPages

Tags: reactjs, deployment, react-router, github-pages

I build and deployed my react app. React App just shows the starting page on Github pages. When I'm trying to switch page 404 error apear. App With Localhost works perfectly. I don't know what do to. Nothing help so far. My code below:

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "HotelLiveDemo",
  "homepage": "https://JakubSoldek.github.io/HotelLiveDemo/",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cra-template": "1.1.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "react-script-tag": "^1.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
```

router

```js
const Router = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<AboutUs />} />
                <Route path='/hotel' element={<Hotel />} />
                <Route path='/ContactUs' element={<ContactUs />} />
                <Route path='/RoomsPage' element={<RoomsPage />} />

            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a HashRouter instead of a BrowserRouter here when deploying to Github pages.  Github pages does not support browser history, so Github pages gets confused of where to navigate from.

See the end of [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/deploy-a-react-app-to-github-pages/) and also the "Add routing to our application" section [here](https://medium.com/@bennirus/deploying-a-create-react-app-with-routing-to-github-pages-f386b6ce84c2).